# Mailgun Python API: no error message but no message sent as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, mailgun

I want to test my Python program which uses the Mailgun API. When executing the program, I did not get any Terminal output. However, on my [Mailgun dashboard](https://app.mailgun.com/app/dashboard) I do not see that any email was sent and I did not get an email to the specified email as well.

```
import requests

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox***.mailgun.org/messages",  #replaced the actual link
        auth=("api", "key"), #replaced the actual API key with "key"
        data={"from": "User <test@gmail.com>", #replaced mail
              "to": ["User", "Test@gmail.com"], #replaced mail
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})

send_simple_message()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you didn't not get any terminal output, because you never asked for it. You just returned from your function without checking if anything went wrong

Comment: Can you let us know of the result that is returned from the function?

Comment: Now I get `<Response [400]>
{
  "message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings."
}`. However, I have already added the email address to the trusted recipients and it is still showing the error

Comment: You should use your own domain (not the sandbox). This detailed description may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150905/can-i-send-email-with-mailgun-sandbox-domain-under-my-local-os/68542876#68542876