# Sending email with Mailgun account I got the domain is unverified and requires DNS configuration error

Tags: laravel, mailgun

My Laravel 8 app is located at tads.my-demo-apps.tk as a subdomain of my-demo-apps.tk.
This domain is created at https://my.freenom.com/ with Ubunutu 10 installed on ubuntu 18

When I send an email with my yahoo.com account(under which I enter into the main dashboard)
I got the email, ok, but I see not rendered HTML code in the content of the received email.

I try to send an email to my Gmail account I got the error:

```
{"message":"Expected response code 354 but got code \"421\", with message \"421 Domain my-demo-apps.tk is not allowed to send: The domain is unverified and requires DNS configuration. Log in to your control panel to view required DNS records.\r\n\"","user_id":2}
```

Opening the DNS page of my domain, I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14BCg.jpg
But I am not sure which records have I to check and how?

In details of my new Mailgun account, I see

```
Plan    Flex
Emails sent 3 of 1.3K
Validations 0 of 0
Dedicated IPs   0 of 0
Log retention   5 days
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds more like a problem you will get solved in ServerFault

Comment: Please point where is ServerFault and what have I to check ?

Comment: If you want to use Mailgun, you need to set it up. The page you've sent a screenshot on clearly shows what still needs to be set up (eg *TXT records ... are required* and then shows the 2 records that are required).  If it doesn't make sense, check whatever help links you can see on that page.  If that doesn't help, searching for "Mailgun set up" I found [this page which clearly describes domain set up](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html) stuff.

Comment: This detailed description may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150905/can-i-send-email-with-mailgun-sandbox-domain-under-my-local-os/68542876#68542876

Answer (score 0):

You must fill in the DNS records of the domain according to what mailgun asks you.

For example mg.mydomain.com MX Record, etc.

If you don't have access to modify the DNS Records, ask your DNS Provider about it.

Comment: Who is DNS Provider in this case ? freenom.com?
I have access to it. As My application is under “tads.my-demo-apps.tk” hosting : https://imgur.com/a/INWCuTh
Have I to add some new record ?

Comment: I added new line : https://imgur.com/a/5nyYo7h
Is it correct ?